# What C++ standard has better of COM?

Tags: c++, standards

I have see such answer:

> COM is a technique of it's own. It fulfills some special needs but
>   violates a lot of good engineering principles. E.g solid. The standard
>   has better ways than using COM. – mkaes

Very interesting to know what is that "better ways"?

We use in our project IUnknown base class, but not COM technology itself.
IUnknown allows us:

1. have nice specified interface abstract classes;
2. use its add()/release() as basis for intrusive smart ptrs;
3. use mechanism of QueryInterface() to be more effective than dynamic_cast;

Okay, exists boost::intrusive_ptr but it is not in the standard so far. And even if it was there, this will be separate class to solve task of intrusive smart ptr.  Assuming it is there, yes I could do something as

```
interface ITable : intrusive_ptr {}
interface IField : intrusive_ptr {}
```

But what about QueryInterface() mechanism?

P.S. This question is NOT about COM at all.

Comment: interesting site ... moderators have erase here 30 comments, where at least one moderator have said nonsense about COM and ActiveX... So we are moderated by persons who are very active (students?), but are not deep experts? Excellent :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard uses:  composition rather than inheritance in most cases (very little inheritance in the standard library).  Prefers template based generic programming rather than runtime polymorphism.  Prefers value types rather than keeping pointers of unknown ultimate type for everything, everywhere.  All things you should be doing in C++ rather than treating it like Java.

Comment: While I totally abhor 'composition rather than inheritance' idea (just look into standard implementation - everything is inherited from something!), the rest rings very true.

Comment: Okay, yes I know that STL is template library from its born... Guys are you serious that using inheritance, this is Java-style?  How old are you guys? I remember that in 80-83 years, when C++ have come to our hands, we did have only inheritance. Templates was added into C++ later.  I understand that you may be hate Java, me too, but why you put this as argument? :)

Comment: When 'pointers' - have become "Java style" ??

Comment: @RuslanZasukhin, last time I checked year was 2016. Yes, in 1983 C++ was a very different language. We are very lucky to have a much better one now. As for Java style - you didn't know that despite their claim, everything in Java is a pointer (which is not a primitive type)?

Comment: @SergeyA, can I wonder you even more? Despite their claims (PHP, Java, Lisp) everything is made on C/C++ internally, using pointers at the end-level.

Comment: @RuslanZasukhin - You are wrong - It is machine code. ones and zeros if you want to go that far

Comment: @EdHeal this was the NEXT step go to machine codes :)  But this not make wrong my words that PHP language is written on C/C++ itself. yes? As well as most others.

Comment: composition - guys this is one of key-points in that COM technology btw. Actually in OO itself. They have come to idea that inheritance itself is not so effective. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance